# The favicon is displaying on Chrome, FireFox, but it's not on Safari, any clue?

Tags: html, favicon

now I'm struggling with an issue I have when I tried to include a favicon (icon-tab) on the Apple Safari web browser. I want to understand what I missing here.
I read a ton of papers and followed all the considerations they recommend, I think!
I also read that Safari is not displaying the tab-icons until the site is over a domain. Is that true?
My site at this moment is staying local. Could it be affecting?

Many thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head profile="file:///Users/frajadita/.workplace/web\ development/fdt-site/index.html">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="keywords"
      content="Developer, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Marketing, Design, Advisor, Technical, Support, Inspection, NACE, Protective, Marine, Coatings"
    />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Hi, I'm Francisco, CEO of 4Inception. I'm a passionate & dedicated Developer with dense expertise in Marketing, 
      Design, PMC, Corrosion, and expert in device support"
    />
    <meta
      name="author"
      content="@frajadita"
    />

    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Francisco's Site</title>
  
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Serif+Display&family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/fav/Favicon/icon-16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/fav/Favicon/icon-32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/fav/Chrome-Fav/icon-192.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/fav/Apple-Fav/apple-touch-icon-120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/fav/Apple-Fav/apple-touch-icon-152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="images/fav/Apple-Fav/apple-touch-icon-167.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/fav/Apple-Fav/apple-touch-icon-180.png">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="images/fav/Apple-Fav/test-icon.svg" color="#fffff">

  </head>
  
  <body>
```

Comment: I can't speak for Safari specifically, but I will say that, as you've already pointed out, you're likely to run into a lot of issues loading sites from the `file:///` domain. If you haven't already, you should get a local web server (like `php`) and run it from there.

Comment: Thanks, @SilvioMayolo for your comment. I'll follow your recommendation and I'll let you know!